# Tikz: fade out edge through dots halfway through

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have an edge from node A to node B:

```
\draw[] (A) edge (B);
```

This creates an edge as follows:

```
A --------------------------------- B
```

I would like to know what properties I have to fill inside `[]` such that the edge looks as follows:

```
A -------- - - -                     B
```

In other words, the edge should only be visible until the half of the path between A and B (or until some fixed distance would be fine too), and the edge should fade out trough dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly fading, but would this be sufficient? Using `calc`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick]
    \node (A)  at (0,0)  {A};
    \node (B)  at (5,0) {B};
    \draw[] (A) edge ($(A)!0.45!(B)$) edge [dotted] ($(A)!0.55!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result from the code above]

basically, it's drawing a plain `edge` between `A` and 45% of the path from `A` to `B`, and then adds a 10% lenght of dotted path. You can clearly change the numbers (or add more sections, like another one with more spaced dots, or with gray dots, you got the idea).

You can use absolute distances on the line (see section 13.5.4 of the tikz manual, "The Syntax of Distance Modifiers"):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick]
    \node (A)  at (0,0)  {A};
    \node (B)  at (5,3) {B};
    \draw[] (A) edge ($(A)!3cm!(B)$) edge [dotted] ($(A)!3.4cm!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: New output]

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you also know a way to specify it in terms of absolute length?

Comment: @ndrizza Look at the new edit...